# Writing to AWS S3 using python library s3fs fails with EntityTooLarge

Tags: python, boto3

I know that there is a limit in the AWS S3 API for uploading files bigger than 5 gb. In `boto3` I should use `multipart`

I am trying to configure the `S3File` object in `s3fs` to do the same, but I can't figure it out.

I am using (as an example of the error) a very basic code:

```
import s3fs

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

with s3.open("s3://bucket/huge_file.csv", "w") as s3_obj:
   with open("huge_file.csv") as local_file
       s3_obj.write(local_file.read())
```

Where `huge_file.csv` has a size > `5Gb`.

The error I am getting is

```
...
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (EntityTooLarge) when calling  the PutObject operation: Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size

...

File ... /s3fs/core.py" line 1487, in __exit__

self.close()

File ... /s3fs/core.py" line 1454, in close
```

So, the question is How (if it is possible) can I setup `s3fs` to upload files bigger than `5Gb` (How shoud Iconfigure it to do multipart uploading)?

Comment: did you find a solution to this using s3fs? i am having the same issue

Answer (score 6):

I think this [Github](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1123) thread should solve any more problems you have, and to make your life easier I think this is what you are looking for.

```
import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig

# Get the service client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

GB = 1024 ** 3
# Ensure that multipart uploads only happen if the size of a transfer
# is larger than S3's size limit for nonmultipart uploads, which is 5 GB.
config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=5 * GB)

# Upload tmp.txt to bucket-name at key-name
s3.upload_file("tmp.txt", "bucket-name", "key-name", Config=config)
```

Comment: Thank you for the resources @Ravin, but I want to do it from `s3fs`. Should I understand from you answer that it is not possible?

Comment: Sorry @nanounanue as far as I know there isn’t a way to do from s3fs. I will look for a way and let you know if I find anything.